# Java Swing Tabs with multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, tabs, pane

is it possible to create a (new)panel inside a tab when you press a button inside the (current)panel?So that the layout is different to the (current) panel?  For example the button is just "next".

i can't find anything on google, i have the feeling that my approach is not possible. I tried to illustrate it which a picture but i don't have enough points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible as Tim B described using a CardLayout. Take a look and maybe this example will help out a bit.

```
 public class JavaApplication2 extends JFrame {

private JPanel mainPanel, cpOne, cpTwo;
private JButton btnContine, btnGoBack;
private CardLayout c1;

public JavaApplication2()
{
    super("Card Layout");
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    mainPanel.add(cardOne(), "card1");
    mainPanel.add(cardTwo(), "card2");
    c1 = (CardLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout());
    add(mainPanel);
    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);


    btnContine.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        c1.show(mainPanel,"card2");
    });
    btnGoBack.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        c1.show(mainPanel,"card1");
    });
}

private JPanel cardOne()
{
    cpOne = new JPanel();
    btnContine = new JButton("Next Panel");
    cpOne.add(btnContine);
    cpOne.add(new JLabel("First Panel"));
    return cpOne;
}
 private JPanel cardTwo()
{
    cpTwo = new JPanel();
    btnGoBack = new JButton("Previous Panel");
    cpTwo.add(btnGoBack);
    cpTwo.add(new JLabel("SECOND PANEL!!!"));
    return cpTwo;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JavaApplication2 jp = new JavaApplication2();
}

}
```

If you look at my example we are just creating a frame and adding one main panel to this frame. To that main panel we are setting a CARD LAYOUT as the layout manager. From here we can add as many cards as our heart desires! So there are just some little methods to make our panels with buttons. We add them to the main panel as **mainPanel.add(cardOne,"card1")** by showing the method as what to add as the card and then naming it card1. When we run the above program you get something like this:

[image]

and after clicking the button we get this:

[image]

Comment: See also [How to create *great* screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) (Some `alt+print screen` action there would crop those images exactly down to window size.)

Comment: Haha at work and snipping on the fly! Fixed and now the screenshots are perfecto.

Comment: *"Fixed and now the screenshots are perfecto."*  Well.. now you made want to up vote *again!*  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily do this. Use a `CardLayout`, place all the panels you want inside that layout, and then switch between them when they press the button.

See this for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html